# Comparator hystereris

Tags: mosfet, comparator, hysteresis

Can someone help me to understand a little better how the hysteresis work in this circuit? I can understand the explanation below why VTRP- = vgs2-vgs1 = ....

Also, I didn't find the meaning of the term β(beta).What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you realize that the **top** part of the circuit (M3, M6, M7 and M4) make the actual hysteresis by comparing currents?

What feeds the two currents into this circuit? The differential pair M1 and M2!

So what the \$V_{TRP}\$ formula does is describe the relation between that current difference and the difference \$V_{gs,M2}-V_{gs,M1}\$ must have to make the upper part "trip".

Note how \$V_{gs2} = \sqrt(2i_2/\beta_2) + V_{t2}\$, does this look familiar to you? It should as it is derived from the standard formula for \$I_d\$ in saturation mode where \$\beta_2 = K_p \frac{W}{L}\$ (I might have lost a factor 2 in there). So \$\beta_2\$ and \$\beta_2\$ simply refer to the **geometry** (\$\frac{W}{L}\$) of the differential pair transistors.

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie.Very useful help. But I can't understand why someone to use the equation Vgs,M2−Vgs,M1to find the trip point?

Comment: Makes perfect sens to me as you can then describe the voltage difference you need **at the input** to make the circuit flip. It is the standard way of describing a circuit with hysteresis. Suppose this voltage is 100 mV. Then if my incoming (digital) signal is 500 mVpp with 50 mV spikes/noise, I can be sure that the spikes noise is rejected. If \$V_{TRP}\$ was only 10 mV I'd know I would have a problem because then that 50 mV noise/spikes can make the circuit trip. If you have a different/better idea, share it and we can discuss it.

Comment: @vl123 because the left/right side are run at different drain currents forming a input offset voltage for the diffpair.